# Axios onDownloadProgress/onUploadProgress doesn't work anymore?

Tags: javascript, html, axios, progress-bar

I have installed axios as `npm install axios`.

I have simple HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick=handleOnClick()>Click me</button>
<script src="./node_modules/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And index.js:

```
const handleOnClick = () => {
    const opts = {
        onDownloadProgress: function (eventProgress) {
            console.log(eventProgress)
        }
    }
    axios.get("https://picsum.photos/200/300", opts)
        .then(r => console.log(r))
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
}
```

Running that in a Chrome browser will print `eventProgress` object once and whole, not simulating real data upload. [This video of 2022 as I can see axios works as expected](https://www.google.com/search?q=axios+ondownloadprogress&oq=axios+ondownloadprogress&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTILCAEQABgNGBMYgAQyCggCEAAYExgWGB4yCggDEAAYExgWGB4yCggEEAAYExgWGB4yCggFEAAYExgWGB4yCggGEAAYExgWGB4yBggHEEUYPNIBCDQ1MDNqMGo0qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:5a5e96bf,vid:QabJ7e7ku58,st:0). what happend to axios?

Comment: Have you imported axios in your index.js file? `import axios from 'axios';`

Comment: I got the desired behaviour using another URL with Axios 1.6.2, was there any error in your console?

Comment: @HarryHsu no errors, did you try with my code snippet? Which browser and could you give me URL you have tried

Comment: have you tried a bigger image like in the video you linked to?